# Clearing out (or preventing) JavaScriptCore objects building up in UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, memory-management, uiwebview, javascriptcore

I've got a `UIWebView` that is using way too much memory.  The behavior in question involves an HTML/JavaScript page where you can re-color certain areas by tapping them, creating new color layers based on PNG files, but every time the user touches the field (whether they're adding color or re-coloring an existing area) the memory ticks up.  Every touch eats up memory, and it never drops.  This process continues *ad infinitum*, resulting in memory loss at best and an app crash at worst.

After playing around with Activity Monitor and Instruments, I've narrowed it down to a buildup of objects in the `VM: Webkit malloc` category, from the `JavaScriptCore library`.  That makes sense: the page's functionality is JavaScript, and each PNG layer is about 4KB, the same size as the objects that are building up.

So now my question becomes, **what do I do about it?**

I'm kind of new to `UIWebView`, so I was wondering if someone could shed some light on my options?  Is there a way to manually clear out all those unnecessary objects (I tried `[[NSURLCache sharedURLcache] removeAllCachedResponses]` but it did nothing), or prevent them from forming in the first place?

And perhaps most importantly: **is this likely to end up being an iOS solution in the app, or a JavaScript solution on the page?**

Comment: git rid of the old colors when you add new ones.

Comment: Thanks, man, that's really helpful.  I'm working with code I didn't write and I don't know JavaScript, so I'm asking HOW.  Is getting rid of those layers the responsibility of the JavaScript code, or does iOS need to get rid of the objects because the UIWebView is holding onto them?

Comment: it has nothing to do with iOS, the problem start before that level. i can't tell you how to fix the js problem without seeing a lick of code. typically, img.parentNode.removeChild(img) will remove an image, if that's how you're accomplishing the effect. you can also set dynamic elements to null, reset the canvas tag, etc. but cleaning up the mess depends on knowing how you're making the mess.

Comment: Agh.  Well I was hoping to figure out a fix myself, but I guess I just need to forward it on to the JS guys.  Thanks for your insight.

Comment: This also seems to be overkill for what you're doing, seems like you could just accomplish it in UIKit. But I assume there's some reason you *need* UIWebView for it.